# How to remove/toggle hover class on an element (that is translated upon click) without having to move the mouse again?

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, transition

If you click and don't move your mouse you'll see the button's color remaining as red!
What I want accomplish is after you click and don't move the mouse it still removes/toggles `.hover` class.

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robylayouts/u7ntra8e/2/)

```js
$(function() {
  var $Btn = $('.button');

  $Btn.hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
  });


  $Btn.on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active')
    $('.move').toggleClass('angle');
  });
});
```

```css
.move {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: transform .2s ease;
  /* 
        have noticed issue is in "transition" 
    */
}
.button.hover {
  color: red;
}
.angle {
  transform: translate(100px, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="move">
  <button class="button">on click still red?</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/d795jt5o/) what you need?

Comment: Thank you! @Harry
[Result is marvelous!](http://robylayouts.com/file/btn-bug.gif)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element is retaining the `hover` class even after the button is clicked (and container is translated) because the browser doesn't seem to be calling the hover-out (or mouseout) till the mouse is actually moved.

One way to fix this would be to remove the `hover` class within the `click` event handler of the button. But for this to work the `hover` event handler's code needs to be changed to specifically add class on mouseover (hover-in) and remove it on mouseout (hover-out). This is needed because as per current code even though `hover` class is removed within the click event handler, it gets toggled back on the moment the mouse is moved again (because at that point in time, the handler for `hover` doesn't see the class on the element).

The change to the code can actually be done in two ways - either by using separate `mouseover` and `mouseout` functions (like in my original fiddle) or by passing two separate functions to `hover` handler. When two functions are passed, the first one gets called on hover-in and the second on hover-out.

```js
$(function () {
  var $Btn = $('.button');

  $Btn.hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
  },function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  }); /* first function is executed on mouseover, second on mouseout */

  $Btn.on("click", function () {
    $(this).removeClass('hover'); // remove the hover class when button is clicked
    $('.move').toggleClass('angle');
  });
});
```

```css
.move {
  border:1px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: transform .2s ease;
  /* 
  have noticed issue is in "transition" 
  */
}
.button.hover {
  color: red;
}
.angle {
  transform: translate(100px, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="move">
    <button class="button">on click still red?</button>
</div>
```