# Hover state on animated element

Tags: html, css

Browser vendors seem to implement `:hover` in a very broken way: They only change element states when the **mouse** moves, but **not** when **elements** move (CSS animations, etc.). So, say if you click on an element that has a :hover rule that makes it light up, and by clicking you trigger a CSS animation that moves the element away from the mouse pointer, **the element will still stay in the :hover state**, which is of course completely wrong.

I've now implemented my own mouseover handling in a `requestAnimationFrame` callback where I check all elements against mouse position, but seriously, this can't be necessary? Isn't there a way to fix `:hover`?

**Full example:**

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5rem;
  left: 10rem;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  background: red;
  transition: left 0.5s;
}
div.moved {
  left: 30rem;
}
div:hover {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="this.classList.toggle('moved')"></div>
```

I've read the arguments in the comments regarding wasting CPU cycles for constantly checking the hover states of all elements on the page. However, as I said I've implemented this in Javascript (!) inside a `requestAnimationFrame` callback, and I don't notice any measurable decrease in performance. Surely if this were implemented inside the browser's engine, there would be no impact on performance at all. Shouldn't browser vendors implement this correctly, now that it's 2015?

Comment: Please post some code to have a look at your issue. I know what you mean, but to start testing things it's useful to have something to start from.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hzd66e0c/ Is this your example? It seems to work the way you want it to. The :hover is removed when position is changed.

Comment: @Paran0a I can confirm, when clicking the element and no further move movement involved, the element will stay hovered on Chrome and Firefox on OS X 10.11

Comment: @Paran0a this link seems to illustrate the example, in that when (in firefox 42) I click the box the box moves but does *not* revert to the green colour again until the mouse cursor moves.

Comment: @Paran0a No, I think he means something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7fdfo4b9/). Indeed, when you hover over an element, and it moves away, the hover state is still there. I'm surprised as well.

Comment: `Hover` is a relatively old CSS feature and is set from a time when the only moving part of a web page was the cursor, so there's no sense in having hover constantly checking if cursor is OVER the item, that's very processor wasteful, instead it checks if the cursor is over the item *when the cursor moves*. This is less appropriate for moving attributes as you say, but does make sense from a code writing point of view

Comment: At this point we can only guess what the OPs problem is.

Comment: @Paran0a can you not see it? I see the problem, perhaps your browser auto corrects it? Try Bram's jsfiddle link to show a better example, although your example also shows the issue. When the underlaying content moves *but the mouse does not* the hover is not updated to double check if it is still true and adjust the CSS accordingly.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question.

Comment: Firefox doesn't have this problem, or only one part of it: when you take [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fdfo4b9/1/) and just place your mouse somewhere where you know the div will pass, the div won't change colour as soon as its below the cursor. This will only happen if the position of your mouse moves to the div. If you then stop moving your mouse, Firefox *will* remove the hover state as soon as the div has passed.

Comment: *"Shouldn't browser vendors implement this correctly, now that it's 2015?"* - The answer is yes...but since it's baked into all browsers I suspect little effort will be made to "correct" it. Have you filed bug reports? If so, what did they say in response? However, I doubt if there is an answer that would be suitable for SO. GL with this one.

Comment: By no means saying this is a duplicate but here is a related item - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33065242/how-to-remove-toggle-hover-class-on-an-element-that-is-translated-upon-click-w/33065723#33065723 It doesn't have the answer but I am commenting just to leave a link between the two threads which future users can follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hover` is a relatively old CSS feature and is set from a time when the only moving part of a web page was the cursor, so there's no sense in having hover constantly checking if cursor is OVER the item, that's processor wasteful, and would have been considered excessive in a time when elements on a page did not move.

Instead it checks if the cursor is over the element when the cursor moves. This is far less appropriate for moving attributes as you say, but does make sense from a code writing point of view, when it was written there was no need to consider the alternative issues of element movement.

There is no way to immediately update the CSS behaviour itself as this is pretty much coded out of reach of Site designers, so using `javascript` is your only real solution.

You can report this as a bug but this will probably only get corrected as either a new selector ability such as `:HoverUpdate` *[unlikely]* or will be coming out with CSS4 *(I have no idea the status of CSS4, if this really hasn't been noted by those associated with it, then it may even be a CSS5 thing)*.

There are various issues to changing the core behaviour of `hover` on the fly or in a non-centralised way - mainly that each different browser engine *might* adapt the changes in different ways and different versions (We've already found that Firefox handles the `:hover` selector somewhat haphazardly).

The point is, it's not something that can or should be cleanly fixed by the Browsers themselves but should be fixed within the definitions/code of CSS itself as set out by W3C.

On the flip side, those users with mice move them around so much (even just a pixel or two) that it's somewhat questionable your situation outside of a game, where there is a need for the mouse to be in a frozen position and for the hover selector to be constantly checked, as you seem to have already done, I think roll it with `Javascript` can take care of this as a relative edge case and in a couple of years CSS4 *might* have a built in solution.

**Next Steps**

- Report a Bug to each browser builder
- Report a feature request to W3C for it as a CSS-4 specification
- Possibly explore if there is a way to get browser plugins to solve this issue (again, haphazard).
- Use Javascript.