# Hover state remains after moving element with transition

Tags: jquery, css, hover, css-transitions, transition

I have two buttons which move around elements of the page, including the buttons themselves. This means that the buttons will move away from the cursor when clicked.
Now, when one of these buttons is clicked, its :hover state will be preserved, meaning that the cursor is still a pointer and the button is displaying its mouseover background.
The weird thing is, this only happens for one of them, not the other.

I've come across a lot of questions with basically the same problem, but have found no working solutions.

Only tested on FF 49.0.2.

### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0s1Ljtxt/1/)

Here's the CSS (I use JQuery to toggle the vertical and leftHand classes):

```
/* *** INTERFACE *** */
    .interface {
        position: absolute; right: 2.16vw;
        width: 29.04vw;
        transition: top 2s, right 2s, width 2s, height 2s;
    }

    #content.leftHand .interface {
        right: 68.8vw;
    }

    #content.vertical .interface {
        top: 68.8vh !important;
        height: 29.04vh !important;
    }

    .interface > div {
        position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
        width: 27.94vw;
        margin: auto;
        transition: height 2s, width 2s;
    }

    #content.vertical .interface > div {
        height: 27.94vh !important;
    }

    #settings {
            top: 2.09vh;
            height: 10.15vh;
        }

        #content.vertical #settings {
            right: 3.29vw;
            width: 10.15vw;
        }

        #content.vertical.leftHand #settings {
            right: 86.57vw;
        }

        #settingsContainer {
            height: 8.65vh;
        }

        #content.vertical #settingsContainer {
            width: 8.65vw;
        }

        #settingsContainer div {
            width: 100%; height: 100%;
            margin: 0; padding: 0;
        }

        #settings span {
            position: absolute; top: 0.52vh; display: block;
            width: 5.2vw; height: 7.61vh;
            transition: top 2s, left 2s, width 2s, height 2s;
        }

        #settings button {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%; height: 100%;
            cursor: pointer;
            border: 0;
                background-color: rgba(230, 0, 225, 1);
            transition: opacity 1.5s;
        }

        #content.vertical #settings span {
            left: 0.52vw !important;
            width: 7.61vw; height: 5.2vh;
        }

        /* SwitchHand & Rotate */           
            #switchHandBtn {
                left: 0.32vw;
            }

            #content.leftHand #switchHandBtn {
                left: 22.4vw;
            }

            #content.vertical #switchHandBtn {
                top: 0.32vh;
            }

            #content.leftHand #switchHandBtn:not(:hover) #rightHandBtn, #content:not(.leftHand) #switchHandBtn:not(:hover) #leftHandBtn,
            #content.leftHand #switchHandBtn:hover #leftHandBtn, #content:not(.leftHand) #switchHandBtn:hover #rightHandBtn {
                opacity: 0;
            }

            #rotateBtn {
                left: 5.84vw;
            }

            #content.leftHand #rotateBtn {
                left: 16.88vw;
            }

            #content.vertical #rotateBtn {
                top: 5.84vh;
            }

            #content.vertical #rotateBtn:not(:hover) #rotateHorBtn, #content:not(.vertical) #rotateBtn:not(:hover) #rotateVertBtn,
            #content.vertical #rotateBtn:hover #rotateVertBtn, #content:not(.vertical) #rotateBtn:hover #rotateHorBtn {
                opacity: 0;
            }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33065242/how-to-remove-toggle-hover-class-on-an-element-that-is-translated-upon-click-w?rq=1) in the related questions. It looks promising, will try it soon. However, the fact that the up/down button doesn't have the same problem makes me suspect there's a non-JS solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, looks like I actually already found an answer to my own question.
The reason the vertical transition doesn't retain the hover state is because it changes the moved element's size as well, whereas the horizontal transition doesn't.
If you want to "update" the hover state, you will have to force the element to redraw, which can be done by changing the height or width.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0s1Ljtxt/2/)

```
#content.leftHand .interface {
        right: 68.8vw;
/* FIXED: changing the size forces a redraw of the element, causing the hover state to update */
    width: 29.05vw !important;
    }
```